# how to change the layout margin for an Android ListView Programmatically

Tags: android, listview

I have defined a List View in xml as below

```
     <ListView android:id="@+id/mylist" 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_marginTop="95dip"/>
```

And i need to re-define the layout margin upon some result in my programe ,how i can achieve this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you get hold of the ListView object in your Activity you can use the method [setLayoutParams()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)), passing in an instance of   [android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html).

Answer (score 25):

More simply, you may be able to modify the existing MarginLayoutParams instance to modify the margin:

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mListView
        .getLayoutParams();

mlp.setMargins(adjustmentPxs, 0, 0, 0);

break;
```

Comment: You can also set specific margins directly using this fashion (i.e mlp.leftMargin = 8).